# Nodejs : merging functions using callbacks

Tags: node.js, generics, callback

For these two functions :

```
  function isSuspended (status){
    if(status  === 'suspended'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }


 function isSubscribed(status){
    if(status  === 'subscribed'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Using Nodejs :

1- How can i merge both functions into one function with callback?

2- What is the benefit of using callbacks in such situation?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please explain what you want as output?

Answer (score 0):

Here you don't need to use a callback, you can simply merge them in the following manner:

```js
function isSuspendedOrSubscribed(status) {
  return (status === 'suspended') || (status === 'subscribed');
}

console.log(isSuspendedOrSubscribed('suspended'));
console.log(isSuspendedOrSubscribed('subscribed'));
console.log(isSuspendedOrSubscribed('random'));
```

Use callback when a certain action needs to be performed after a certain event happened. For instance:

```js
setTimeout(()=> console.log('I am needed as a callback function to be executed after the timer') ,1000)
```

Thus could also be useful for things like reaching out to the web or connecting to a database (async operations)

Comment: Thanks alot for ur answer , but arent callbacks used to make functions more generic too ? 
For example , instead of writing 3 functions logging 3 different outputs depending on functions arguments , i can merge them into one using callback function  ?

Answer (score 0):

Callback in Nodejs is used to handle the asynchronous activities of the function. A callback function is called at the end of the completion of the task.

In your case we don't need callback but if you want then we can use callback like:

```
/*Here `status` could be `suspended` or `subscribed` and 
callback is an function reference for calling 
argumentative function which is available as a `handleSuspendOrSubscribe` parameter.*/

let handleSuspendOrSubscribe = (status, callback)=>{

 if(status == 'suspended' || stataus == 'subscribed'){
     callback(null, true);  // callback first parameter must be error and 2 must be success, It is called `error first callback`

 }else{
     callback(true, null);
 }
}
```

`Now I am going to call handleSuspendOrSubscribe function like`

```
handleSuspendOrSubscribe('suspended', function(err, success){
    err ? console.log('Error: ', err) : console.log('Success: ', success);
})
```